# how to fix response null with chrome.tabs.sendmessage?

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

so i am working on an chrome extension but i get a response undefined when trying to make the extension click on a button. I am using chrome.tabs.sendmessage. anyone knows why i get response undefined?

## input

```
{
    "response_defined": false,
    "tabId": {},
    "messageToSend": {
        "QuerySelector": "button[name='requestor-next']"
        "custom value": "null"
    }
}

tabId: Promise
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: 307593939
```

## code

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(await tabId, messageToSend, (response: AutomationMessage) => {
                this.log({ msg: "RecieveMessage", response, querySelector });
                this.log({ response });
                this.log({ querySelector });
                this.log({ chromerror: chrome.runtime.lastError });
                if (response && response.QuerySelector == querySelector && response.MessageType != AutomationMessageType.StartedLoading) {
                    console.log("resolved")
                    resolve(querySelector);
                } else if (response?.MessageType == AutomationMessageType.StartedLoading) {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        resolve(querySelector);
                    }, 1000);
                }
                else {
                    this.log({response_defined: response != undefined, response, tabId, messageToSend});
                }
            });
setTimeout(() => {
                reject(`Promise timed out after ${3000} ms`);
            }, 3000);
```

## output

```
{
"response": undefined
"Promise timed out after 3000 ms"
}
```

Comment: Show your onMessage listener. Show how you declare/load/inject that code.